# My Apache server doesn't work from ServerName

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have an apache server on apache v2.2 and I cannot acces the website from name server, only from IP address(from other computer) or localhost(on same server)
I have this configuration under httpd.conf

```
Listen 80

ServerName localhost:80

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot  "C:/Toolkit/wwwroot"
ServerName configuration.tw.net
#ServerAlias configuration.tw
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
#Other directives here
CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

With configuration.tw.net I cannot acces the website, only from the ip of the server.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: "ServerName localhost:80" is not required. Please remove it. Also make sure the host/server name "configuration.tw.net" is mapped to the correct IP address in the DNS. You can verify this by doing a ping.

Comment: Unfortunately when I do ipconfig the Connection-specific DNS Suffix.: is empty and if I do a nslookup I got this entry Server: Unknown . I will fix this and I think that will fix my problem. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Update if it resolves the issue so that the loop can be closed.

Comment: The issue was fixed, thank you Roshith